# Weblogic 12c - JAX-WS NPE

Tags: jax-ws, weblogic12c

I'm using Weblogic 12c. After migrating from Weblogic 11g to 12c, web service started to throw the following error. (Application is deployed successfully, the error is threw at every invoke)

```
com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: null   java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseWSLocalObject.__WL_preInvoke(BaseWSLocalObject.java:106)
at com.less.talk.ws.endpoint.MyService_5m5a9k_WSOImpl.__WL_myMethod_WS_preInvoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at weblogic.wsee.server.ejb.WsEjb.preInvoke(WsEjb.java:50)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSEjbInstanceResolver$WLSEjbInvoker.invoke(WLSEjbInstanceResolver.java:193)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:91)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:199)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:640)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:284)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:293)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3443)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3413)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2196)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1632)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0 and it was caused because I had enabled DebugEjbInvoke logging.

- Environment -> Servers -> AdminServer -> Debug

  - weblogic -> ejb -> invoke: **DebugEjbInvoke** --> Disabled solved the issue

My stacktrace: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseWSLocalObject.__WL_preInvoke(BaseWSLocalObject.java:85)